# Access Denied when creating Personal View

Tags: 2013, permissions, list-view

Good day everyone,

I tried to create a special permissions group in SP2013 to allow users to create a personal view of a list but not have any edit rights on the items, for auditing purposes, but the user is getting Access Denied error when they attempt to save the new view. . . Has anyone else experienced this problem?

I have granted the following rights to this permissions group:
View Items
Open Items
View Versions
Create Alerts
View Application Pages
View Pages
Browse User Information
Open
Edit Personal User Information
Manage Personal Views
Add/Remove Personal Web Parts
Update Personal Web Parts

Answer (score 0):

I'm a complete idiot. Permissions were trimmed for the list and I overlooked that. Once I added the new group directly to the list everything worked.

No mystery to solve here.